# Aurelia - Update a field when a typeAhead field has a value selected

Tags: aurelia

I am having trouble with this.  I have seen [this post](http://www.sobell.net/detecting-changes-to-objects-in-aurelia/) and [this post](https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-binding-behaviors/) its not quite what I require.

I have a typeAhead for suburb that fetches the results from the server.

It works but part of the list of each of the objects that returns is the postcode which I want to update in the field next to it.

Each suburb object in the list has the following members.

```
   id
   name
   postcode
   state
```

Start typing in the suburb field and a list of these suburbs displays (name only - see below "key=name") in a dropdown. Select one and I want to have the postcode field being populated from the information in the suburb object selected.

Can I trigger an update to the postcode field based on a selection in the suburb field??

**CODE**

Here is the Fetch that retrieves the list of suburb objects.

```
 // Fetch for async suburb dropdown.
    getSuburbData(filter: string, limit: number) {
    const headers = this.authService.header();

    if (this.address) {

    }
    else {
        console.log('undefined')
    }
    const queryStringValues = {
        query: filter,
        stateShortName: this.companyStateShortName
    };

    const queryString = "?" + Object.keys(queryStringValues)
        .filter(key => typeof queryStringValues[key] !== "undefined" && queryStringValues[key] !== null)
        .map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(queryStringValues[key])}`)
        .join("&");

    console.log("queryStringValue; ", queryString)

    let suburb = fetch("/api/selectData/QuerySuburbs" + queryString, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(suburbs => filter.length > 0 ? suburbs.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) > -1) : suburbs)
        .then(suburbs => limit ? suburbs.splice(0, limit) : suburbs);  // Not really needed - its done on the server.

    console.log("suburb", suburb);
    return suburb
  }
}
```

Here is the suburb typeahead and the postcode in my view:

```
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label pull-right" for="suburb">Suburb:&nbsp;</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <aubs-typeahead data.call="getSuburbData(filter, limit)"
                                        value.bind="address.suburb"
                                        debounce.bind="350"
                                        placeholder="Suburb..."
                                        open-on-focus.bind="true"
                                        key="name"
                                        results-limit.bind="10"
                                        select-single-result.bind="true"
                                        id="suburb">
                        </aubs-typeahead>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                          <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-5">Postcode:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="col-md-4">
                            <strong>${postcode.length > 0 ? address.postcode : '-'}</strong>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How would I automatically change the postcode value based on a change in the suburb field - ie someone selected a suburb name in the suburb dropdown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a `postcode` property on the view model that needs to be updated when something is selected in typeahead? If that's the case, [Aurelia Bootstrap Typeahead](https://tochoromero.github.io/aurelia-bootstrap/#/typeahead) has `on-select` property/function which you can bind to:

```html
<aubs-typeahead 
    ...
    on-select.call="suburbSelected(item)" 
    ...>
```

and in view model:

```js
suburbSelected(item) {
    if (item) {
        this.postcode = item.postcode;
    } else {
        this.postcode = null;
    }
}
```

Note that depending on your requirements you could also bind directly to selected suburb's postcode. This is possible because you have `value.bind="address.suburb"` which is a two-way binding. `address.suburb` will be updated whenever suburb is selected in typeahead.

```html
<strong>
    ${(address.suburb && address.suburb.postcode) ? address.suburb.postcode : '-'}
</strong>
```

You can also have that as a computed property or some [alternatives to computed](http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-computed-from-patterns/).